# ERROR 1045 (28000): Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench

Полное сообщение ошибки: ERROR 1045 (28000): Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: ═х эрщфхэ єърчрээ√щ ьюфєы№.Library path is 'C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.dll'

Не загружается какой-то модуль при попытке запустить mysql -u root через XAMPP.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На моём пк также установлен MySQL WORKBENCH с уже созданным сервером(не уверен, что это пишется так, надеюсь, что смысл понятен)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правильно ли я понимаю, что следует пытаться как-то совместить обе субд, потому что они конфликтуют. Или это только с "сервером". В интернете масса решений этого вопроса, но все они связаны с MySQL и я не знаю как их адаптировать под мой вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне всё-таки удалось решить эту проблему и решение как обычно лежало на поверхности. Как бы я не изменял конфиги в XAMPP базисом так и оставался 3306, который был "запущен" в mysql workbench, в котором была версия MySQL 8.0, в XAMPP MYSQL 5.7(об этом ниже). Решение проблемы, это запуск с портом 3307:

`mysql.exe -u root -P 3307`

После этого плагины аутентификации перестали конфликовать.

По моим предположениям было примерно так: в properties.ini была строчка `mysql_arguments = -u root -P 3306`, я её изменил на `mysql_arguments = -u root -P 3307`. После почему-то в консоли при вызове команды `mysql.exe -u root -P` mysql всёравно подключалась к порту 3306, а порт в свою очередь был занят MySQL WorkBench, поэтому он и ссылался на непонятный мне каталог(его не существует), а ссылался потому что в XAMPP установлена версия MySQL 5.7, в этой версии использовался ещё "старый" плагин аутентификации. Несмотря на то что изменение файла properties.ini не дало никаких результатов в запуске mysql.exe, но натолкнула на мысль, что в качестве параметра можно передавать порты. Соответственно, я ввёл команду `mysql.exe -u root -P 3307` и он подключился к порту, который я ранее создавал в самом XAMPP через изменение файлов конфигурации и настроек MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло следующее. Суть этого способа в том, что бы изменить метод аутентификации с sha2 на предыдущий. Изменить нужно лишь метод аутентификации и ничего больше.
Открываете MySQL Installer-Community (если установлена не Community версия, а другая, то последним словом может быть название этой версии, например Enterprise). Напротив MySQL Server нажимаете Reconfigure. В появившимся окне нажимаете кнопку Next, пока не дойдете до вкладки Authentication Method. В этой вкладке выбираете Use Legacy Authentication Method (Retain MySQL 5.x Compability). Нажимаете Next. Вводите пароль от root'ового пользователя. Нажимаете Next ничего не изменяя. В последней вкладке, нажимаете Execute для сохранения изменений.